# Is it possible to treat two lines as one?

Tags: java, android, string

Lines:

```
 This is the first line and it is long line1.
 This is the second line and it is long line2.
```

Obviously, these two lines contain "\n" at the end.

But when the device screen is small, at some point.

Default Output:

```
  This is the first line and
  it is long line1.
  This is the second line and
  it is long line2.
```

Expected Output:

```
  This is the first line and
  This is the second line and
  it is long line1.
  it is long line2.
```

Besides using ReplacementSpan to draw first line above the second line, as a workaround I was wondering if it is possible to treat those two lines as one. What options do I have to achieve such output?

Comment: Your "expected output" is to jumble the sentences together into a meaningless mish-mash?

Comment: The expected seems not right.

Comment: Yes , it is ... :D  but to be precise, I always want the same words from first and second line to be at the same position like 'this' to 'this' and 'long' to 'long'..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: One man's trash is another man's treasure. lol

Comment: Your case is ridiculous :|, maybe you should give another example with some meaningful text. Also you should give the view you are using, one TextView? the screenshot you expect

Answer (score 1):

The "logical" solution would be to replace the first line break `\n` by a space.

But in your case it seems you want a horizontally scrolling text view:

```
<TextView 
    android:lines="2"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" ... />
```

I am not sure about the `lines` and `singleLine` attribute.